# Signal to noise ratio with noise equivalent power

Tags: photons, particle-detectors, photonics

I am reading this [document](https://www.thorlabs.com/images/TabImages/Noise_Equivalent_Power_White_Paper.pdf) about the noise equivalent power (NEP). I want to calculate the signal to noise ratio for a photon detector.

I denote the signal power as $P_s$. The width of the signal is $\Delta f_s$ and the bandwidth where the detector can measure a signal is $\Delta f_d$. We have the situation that $\Delta f_s\ll \Delta f_d$. The noise equivalent power is NEP $=10^{-20}{\rm W/}\sqrt{\rm Hz}$.

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise-equivalent_power) I find that the signal to noise ratio is

SNR $=P_s/{\rm NEP}$.

However this cannot be true since this would have units Hz! What is really meant here? Do they mean that

SNR $=P_s/{\rm NEP}\times\sqrt{\tau}$

where $\tau$ is the measurement time?

If this is true, does the SNR then not depend on $\Delta f_s$ and $\Delta f_d$?